# what are these error messages displayed during boot-up of kali from grub boot loader?how can i fix them?

Tags: boot, kali-linux, dual-boot, kvm

[image: error messages during boot-up]

I have a dual booted system which uses grub boot loader to select the OS.KALI is installed on my Sony VAIO VGN FZ21e (quite old laptop) which works fine with windows(the other OS).I have just installed KALI updated it using the terminal and on booting it starting showing these messages.Also my webcam doesnt work(maybe because i had to change the motherboard)but the windows doesnt display any error although webcam doesn't work on either of them.
i m  completely  new to linux and terminal so if you do suggest me something i would be grateful if you explained with commands.
a few other problems such as freezing of different program windows when i resize them using toggle buttons and too much usage of CPU.
thanking anyone who helps me.
Theblank
(also please do explain what is kvmor uvcvideo)

Answer (score 1):

1. The top three messages tell you that the filesystem is being repaired after you powered it off without first shutting down cleanly.
2. The next two messages advise you that virtualisation has been disabled in the BIOS.
3. The next two messages warn you that there is an unspecified problem accessing your webcam.

If you're "new to Linux" then [why are you using Kali Linux](https://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux)? You'll find that you are unlikely to get a lot of help here if you are [a beginner trying to use Kali](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me), because it is not a beginner's distribution.

Comment: Sir, thank you for the reply and can you tell me how to fix it.i actually considered to install another beginners linux OS But i dont know whether i can install another linux operating system in a dual booted system with grub (please do answer it too) and i was hesistant because i installed the OS nearly 8 times until i got it actually installed.thanks alot again

Comment: Beginners' distributions include Mint, Ubuntu and possibly Fedora. There may be others.